# How I solve the recurrence error of FindMaximumSubarray using divide and conquer approach?

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer, clrs

This is my solution to findMaximumSubarray, I follow CLRS Pseudo code algorithm and I get this recursion error I tried to figure out why, but I reach nothing !

I can't understand this part of recursion, the first line is to find divide left array until reaching the base case which is one element, then my brain is blowing I can't imagine what after that !

```
 leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, low, mid)
 rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, mid, high)
 crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum = MaxCrossSubarray(array, low, mid, high)
```

this is the whole code.

```
array = [0,1,-2,3,4,-2, 5, -1, 10, -2 ,11,9, -5, -10, 12]
low = 0 
high = len(array)

mid  = len(array)//2


def MaxCrossSubarray(array, low, mid, high):
    sum = 0
    left_sum = float('-inf')
    for i in range(mid, low, -1):
        sum = sum+array[i]
        if sum > left_sum:
            left_sum = sum 
            max_left = i
    right_sum = float('-inf')
    sum = 0
    for i in range(mid+1, high):
        sum = sum+array[i]
        if sum > right_sum:
            right_sum = sum 
            max_right = i
    return (max_left, max_right, left_sum+right_sum)

def FindMaxSubarray(array, low, high):
    if high == low :
        return (low, high, array[low])
    else:
        mid = (high+low)//2 
        leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, low, mid)
        rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, mid, high)
        crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum = MaxCrossSubarray(array, low, mid, high)
        if leftSum >= rightSum and leftSum >=crossSum:
            return (leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum)
        elif rightSum >= leftSum and rightSum >=crossSum:
            return (rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum)
        else:
            return (crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum)

low, high, sum = FindMaxSubarray (array, low, high)
```

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: `for i in range(mid,low-1, -1): ` low-1 is my error, because `range` reach 1 not 0 and stop which my low is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 leftLow, leftHigh, leftSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, low, mid)
 rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, mid, high)
 crossLow, crossHigh, crossSum = MaxCrossSubarray(array, low, mid, high)
```

The idea in the above code is that you are finding the max of subarray to the right, left and crosssum of the array. As you explained in the question `the first line is to find divide left array until reaching the base case which is one element`. This is correct and the same logic applies to the other parts.

The recursive issue is stemming from this line

```
rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, mid, high)
```

Where `mid=0` and `high = 1`And this then causes the recursive error since under these values the following would always be false.

```
if high == low :
    return (low, high, array[low])
```

To solve the recursive issue, simply change to this

```
rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum = FindMaxSubarray(array, mid+1, high)
```

This ensures that a return condition can be met and so prevents the recursive error.

Having changed that it seems like your `MaxCrossSubArray` is not logically correct and gives the following error upon running it

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_right' referenced before assignment

Look into and see if you can solve it.

**N.B:**  The CLRS is known to contain some errors and it is relatively old. So I would advise you to not stick with the same solution but look for other possibilities. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) for example.